# Google App script: Create a google spreadsheet from byte array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a google spreadsheet from the byte array of Microsoft Excel. Below is the code which is not working:

```
  var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteArray);
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("test");
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder("test");
  }

  var resource = 
   {
     title: fileName,
     mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
     parents: [{ id: folder.getId() }]
   };
   var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource,ss);
```

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Not working could mean a lot of different things. Don't just dump the code, be more specific.

Comment: I don't think that the `Utilities.newBlob()` method can convert file types.  You're basically trying to do a file conversion from Excel to Sheets, which `Utilities.newBlob()` doesn't do.    I'd try the code at the following GitHub link: [https://gist.github.com/azadisaryev/ab57e95096203edc2741](https://gist.github.com/azadisaryev/ab57e95096203edc2741)

Comment: @AntonDementiev, In nutshell, spreadsheet is not created successfully.

Comment: Can you provide the script for retrieving `byteArray`?

Comment: What do you mean "byte array of Microsoft Excel"? If you have an Excel file then you can use GAS to convert it to a Google Sheet. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Finally found the solution, I had to decode the input like  `var ss = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(byteArray));`